# Rebase or Merge to distant ancestor branches?

Tags: git

We've duplicated our production environment and installed the newest version of software.
Code changes are needed for the new environment.
At the same time changes are being made to the old environment.

- Can we merge changes from the old environment to both the new and old master branch? (Do they need to have a common ancestor?)
- Should this be done with merges or rebase?

Thanks

Comment: In general, _backports_ are done with cherry-picking if the branches are too distant. You might try developing on top of an old common ancestor and then merge into the old and the new branches.... but if they are too distant, there might be no point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to merge histories with no common ancestor, you *can* (use the `--allow-unrelated-histories`), but it may not go smoothly since there is no good merge base.  (Basically code the two have in common "looks like" a conflict to git, because the starting point for the merge is an empty working directory.  While common-code conflicts often auto-resolve, they can interfere with how truly conflicting sections show up, making things considerably more difficult.)

It's possible that rebase will go more smoothly, since a patch might apply cleanly to a commit with similar content even though the history doesn't show them as related.

Or, if there is some point in each history where corresponding commits have the same content, you could use `git replace` to temporarily meld the histories at that point, and then perform the merge.

Comment: If I create a single root branch for both servers does that cure the common ancestor issue? Perhaps a MASTER, branch "OLD SERVER" from MASTER, branch "NEW SERVER" from master

Comment: It depends what content is introduced on those branches.  If you just mean to play a trick of *technically* having a common ancestor by providing an empty commit to fill that role... well, that's effectively what `allow-unrelated-history` already does.  If the actual common history of the two versions exists on the branch, then taht's a normal merge situation so of course it will be fine.